# Reactjs Not able to make a button functional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am designing a sidebar for my react project and I have the sidebar which is functioning correctly as expected. As you will see that I have also created a button that will basically open the sidebar from left to right and close it from right to left. But I was not able to make the button functional. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[This is what I am getting in the output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnOHz.png
This is the file in which I have the sidebar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import './TableStyle.css'

class HomePage extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
    visible: false
  }
}
toggleSidebar(){
this.setState.visible = !this.state.visible
}
render() {
    return (
    <div id = "sidebar">
       <div class = "toggle-btn" onClick = {this.toggleSidebar()}> 
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <ul>
       <NavLink to = "/" style={{color: "white"}}>Home</NavLink>
        <p></p>
       <NavLink to = "/data" style={{color: "white"}}>Show all entries</NavLink>
       </ul>
       </div>
       </div>
```

This is TableStyle.css

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
#sidebar {
position: fixed;
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
background: rgb(58, 68, 77);
}
/* #sidebar.active{
left: 0px;
} */
#sidebar ul{
color: rgb(240, 243, 245);
list-style: none;
padding: 15px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
transition: all 500ms linear;
}
#sidebar.active{
left: 0px;
}
#sidebar.toggle-btn {
position: absolute;
left: 230px;
top: 30px;
}
#sidebar .toggle-btn span {
display: block;
width: 30px;
height: 3px;
background: white;
margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you using ```visible```? I only see the state declaration and you updating it in the onClick handler

Comment: Do I need to use it? Because I only thought that updating would work. And if that's the case, can you please explain why and where to use visible? I am a newbie to react so anything would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have different styles for the open vs. closed sidebar? You need to use ```visible``` to change styles dynamically. You mentioned in the post that the navbar works? Are you having trouble closing it or opening it?

Comment: Navbar is just static over there. I am not able to close or open the navbar

Comment: So the navbar is permanently open right? It looks that way from the photo. You need to render an empty div if visible is false, and render the navbar if visible is true

Comment: Yes the navbar is permanently open

Comment: Yeah check @Niklas solution. You can implement it multiple ways but the basic point is that you need to render the navbar (or different styles) when visible is true and close it when false.

Comment: @GrantSingleton Can you please elaborate what you mean by "You need to render an empty div if visible is false, and render the navbar if visible is true ". Thanks in advance

Comment: The better solution is probably to just have different css for the open and closed navbar. But another option is to render different jsx depending on the state of ```visible```.  Such as ```if(visible) return (the code you already have) else return (the closed version of the navbar)```

Comment: It can be ```else return <div />``` or ```return null``` if your button for opening the navbar is outside of this component.

Comment: Oh ok now I understood but for the condition, I need to manually change the value of visible from false true if I want to see the navbar. Otherwise, it is just retuning <div />. And also I am looking for the better option which is to create a new css file. But I am wondering why would we need to create a new css file?

Comment: Just think about it for a minute. You are rendering the navbar, its not going to dissappear unless you render something else. I recommend getting a firm grasp on what is going in your code. You will have two "states" for this component. One state is when visible is true and therefore the navbar is rendered. The other is when visible is false and the navbar is not rendered. You have to decide how you want to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the React Hook useState instead, you don't need an internal state in this case, here is what I would've done:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './TableStyle.css'

class HomePage extends Component {  
  const [visible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  render() {
  
  return (
  <div id="sidebar">
   <div class="toggle-btn" onClick={setIsVisible(!visible)}> 
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <ul>
       <NavLink to = "/" style={{color: "white"}}>Home</NavLink>
        <p></p>
       <NavLink to = "/data" style={{color: "white"}}>Show all entries</NavLink>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In this way, the button will toggle the `visible` value from `false` to `true` and viceversa. This happens on

`<div class="toggle-btn" onClick={setIsVisible(!visible)}>`

Where `onClick` toggles the `visible` value.

And then use the `visible` value for example in the following:

```
<div id="sidebar" class={visible ? "open-sidebar-class" : "close-sidebar-class"}>
```

The `"open-sidebar-class" : "close-sidebar-class"` is where you would put the class you want to trigger in the sidebar when the menu opens or closes.

Try then doing this example in `TableStyle.css` to see if it works, if it does, then just type in the css attributes you want instead to trigger in the sidebar whenever you click the button.

```
...

.open-sidebar-class {
  background-color:green;
}
.close-sidebar-class {
  background-color:red;
}

...
```

Comment: How is this any different than what he already did? I am a fan of react hooks also but this won't fix his problem.

Comment: Okay I see your edit now and that's much better. Good solution. Im upvoting

Comment: Haha, hey there. Thanks for the upvote and comment, now I've become #CommentGang thanks to you. I hope this helps the author.

Comment: I have tried using React Hook before and it is throwing me that hooks error which is common when you use hooks. So trying to fix that

Comment: Would you mind uploading a picture of the error? I might be able to help you from there.

Comment: I was not able to upload the ss. Just in case if you want to see the error. HEre it is "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

Comment: Ok. Try moving the ```const [visible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);``` line, before the ```render()``` so that it becomes the following (see my post)

Comment: Just a brief note @Heb99 you don't have to switch to react hooks. The point is that you render something different when visible is true. I love React hooks and recommend them but solve your first problem first

Comment: Also @Heb99 you can't use hooks in a class component. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: *"You can’t use Hooks inside a class component,.."*  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#:~:text=You%20can't%20use%20Hooks,implementation%20detail%20of%20that%20component.

Comment: Moving made it worse even.

Comment: Ok, as the other said, you can't have Hooks inside a class component, but it is recommended using React Hooks. What I would to in your situation Heb99, is that you instead add the useState in the file where you use the ```<HomePage/>``` component, and instead send a prop so that it looks something like this ```<HomePage visible={visible} />```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is re-rendering HomePage each time you click on the button, so it resets visibility to false as it executes the component script again.  I can't tell why you are re-rendering from the snippet (and please reformat to usual indentation and I couldn't get it to run in a sandbox bc unclosed brackets), but you can work around by passing the sidebar visibility as a prop to the HomePage component.